# cardano-db-sync sql query for assets of a wallet

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-db-sync

I am trying to develop the PostgreSQL query that will return all the assets of a given stake address and their respective quantities.

What needs to be joined and queried in order to determine what's in a given wallet?

If I query for the tx_out's of a given stake address:

`select * from tx_out where stake_address_id = X order by tx_id desc;`

EDIT:
Here is what I have so far, with summed quantities for grouped fingerprints and not yet with sum of ADA added to result, just the assets...

EDIT 2: With policy added, ordered by quantity of asset. I think is what I wanted, just does not have quantity of ADA row in results yet.

```
SELECT encode(ma.policy::bytea, 'hex') as policy, ma.fingerprint, SUM(matxo.quantity) AS total_quantity
FROM tx_out AS txo
LEFT JOIN tx_in AS txi ON txo.tx_id = txi.tx_out_id AND txo.index::smallint = txi.tx_out_index::smallint 
LEFT JOIN tx ON tx.id = txo.tx_id
LEFT JOIN block ON tx.block_id = block.id 
LEFT JOIN stake_address AS sa ON txo.stake_address_id = sa.id 
LEFT JOIN ma_tx_out AS matxo ON matxo.tx_out_id = txo.id 
LEFT JOIN multi_asset AS ma ON ma.id = matxo.ident 
WHERE sa.view = '<stake_address_here>' 
  AND txi.tx_in_id IS NULL 
  AND block.epoch_no IS NOT NULL 
  AND ma.policy IS NOT NULL 
group by ma.fingerprint, ma.policy 
order by total_quantity desc;
```

Comment: Have you looked at the "interesting queries" document linked from the README in the github repo?

Comment: Hi Erik, thank you - yes, I have examined those, as well as the schema, and the ERD.

https://github.com/IntersectMBO/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/interesting-queries.md#get-all-assets-with-quantities-and-count-of-mints

There is the "Get all assets with quantities and count of mints" query in the interesting queries doc, but it does not retrieve for a given address / stake address..?

Comment: I added what I have so far as an edit to my question - see what you think could be better or should be done different @ErikdeCastroLopo ?

Comment: I have not tried to run that query, but it seems ok,

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I have found returns the assets, and their respective quantities, for a given stake address. Enjoy!

`SELECT encode(ma.policy::bytea, 'hex') as policy, ma.fingerprint, SUM(matxo.quantity) AS total_quantity FROM tx_out AS txo LEFT JOIN tx_in AS txi ON txo.tx_id = txi.tx_out_id AND txo.index::smallint = txi.tx_out_index::smallint  LEFT JOIN tx ON tx.id = txo.tx_id LEFT JOIN block ON tx.block_id = block.id  LEFT JOIN stake_address AS sa ON txo.stake_address_id = sa.id  LEFT JOIN ma_tx_out AS matxo ON matxo.tx_out_id = txo.id  LEFT JOIN multi_asset AS ma ON ma.id = matxo.ident  WHERE sa.view = '<stake_address_here>'  AND txi.tx_in_id IS NULL  AND block.epoch_no IS NOT NULL  AND ma.policy IS NOT NULL  group by ma.fingerprint, ma.policy  order by total_quantity desc;`